# how to apply the dual javascript function in single object?

Tags: javascript, html, object

I have one object javascript function:

```js
var one = function(id)
{
  load : function(data){
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=data;
  }
  }

one('demo').load('test');
```

```html
<p id="demo">
  
  </p>
```

i need to apply the dual javascript function inside single object.but not getting any result.please suggests anyone.

> example like : jquery `$('#demo').html('data')`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something this:

```js
var one = function(id){
    return {
        element : document.getElementById(id),
        load  : function(data){
            var ele = this.element;
            if(!!ele){
                // There is an element with the provided id. So set it's innerHTML.
                ele.innerHTML = data; 
            }
        }
    }
}

one('demo').load('test');
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Your function now returns an object with two properties, one the element whose `id` is the id you pass and one function that loads the data you pass to this element.